# how to send notification from android app to asp.net server using firebase android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, .net, firebase

I know how to send notifications from Asp.net server to android app. But what i want to do is to be able send notification form my android app to firebase server when some event happens in my app. Is that possible? If so, how to achieve it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need to send a notification to the server. Instead you can call API from Android and get work done.

Comment: Great. That was my ultimate place to go to. I just needed to know if it was possible to do so.

Comment: Is there any admin module present? If yes, then a person should handle all the admin part. Admin portal/Website will receive notification.

Comment: Yes It is possible. You need to call API from android. Then that api will send notification to browser. Firebase supports web notification.